# How to stop google mapview animating when initially loaded in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am using google map view in my ears application everything works fine, but I just want my movie shouldn't animate from sea to my location when initially gets loaded I want to stop that. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens as you get your current location seconds after your view is loaded. If you want to stop doing that, what you can do is add location manager to your splash screen(Launch Screen) and wait till you get the location. When you do, pass that location to your view controller and animate to the location in viewWillAppear method. Hope that helps.